# Download a spreadsheet from a folder using Google Drive api

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a Google drive repository where I used to upload lots of files. This time I would like to download something from this same repository.

The following code works to download a file with file_id:

```
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

file_id = '23242342345YdJqjvKLVbenO22FeKcL'
  request = team_drive.DRIVE.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
  fh = io.BytesIO()
  downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
  done = False
  while done is False:
       status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
       print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
  fh.seek(0)
  with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
       shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f, length=131072)
```

I would like to do the same but download a file from a folder this time. I tried the following code to display files in a given folder with folder_id. But it does not work.

```
folder_id = '13223232323237jWuf3__hKAG18jVo'
results = team_drive.DRIVE.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and parents in '"+folder_id+"'",fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",pageSize=400).execute()
```

Should the code work? I got an empty list. Any contribution would be appreciated

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about your question? 1. What is `a Google drive repo`? 2. What is `team_drive.DRIVE`? 3. In your script, I thought that you might be trying to retrieve the file list. But in your title, `Download a speadsheet using Google Drive api`. I cannot understand about your goal. So can I ask you about the detail of your current situation and your goal?

Comment: I've used this https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited. Could you look and tell me if you need something else?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I could understand about `DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))` and also you want to download the files in a folder. I have 4 more questions. 1. `1mZv7d7rB6g_5YdJqjvKLVbenO22FeKcL` is one of files in the folder? 2. Does the folder has the subfolders including the files? 3. About `I got an empty list.`, if an error occurs, can you provide it? 4. The folder is in the shared Drive? If it's so, do yo have the permission for downloading the files?

Comment: @Tanaike Tank you. Here are my answers. 1. My objective is to download the latest file (uploaded) just by providing the folder_id. I don't wish to provide file_id (even if my example is doing so). And yes `1mZv7d7rB6g_5YdJqjvKLVbenO22FeKcL` is a file in the folder. 2. No subfolders. 3. No error has  occurred at this point. 4. I am the manager  on the share Drive.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that the sample file ID is in the folder on your shared Drive. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding. From your replying, I would like to confirm for your goal. 1. From `the latest file`, you want to download only one file, which is the latest modified time, from the folder in the shared Drive. And, you want to achieve your goal using googleapis for python. [Ref](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) Is my understanding correct?

Comment: By the way, in your script, the file which is not Google Docs is downloaded. When you want to download a Google Spreadsheet which is the latest modified time, it is required to convert to other format like Excel, PDF and so on. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike 1. you are correct. About the download I could do. It is a .xlsx file that I have downloaded successfully in csv

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please confirm whether my understanding is correct. If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal and situation as follows.

- You want to download the Google Spreadsheet, which is the latest modified time, from the specific folder in your shared Drive as the XLSX format.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.
- You have already been able to download the file using Drive API.

For this, I would like to propose the following sample script. The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the latest Google Spreadsheet from the specific folder in the shared Drive.

   - For this, I use `results = DRIVE.files().list(pageSize=1, fields="files(modifiedTime,name,id)", orderBy="modifiedTime desc", q="'" + folder_id + "' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'", supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()`
   - By this, the Google Spreadsheet with the latest modified time can be retrieved.
2. Retrieve the file ID of latest Google Spreadsheet.

   - In this case, `results.get('files', [])[0]['id']` is the file ID.
3. Download the Google Spreadsheet as the XLSX format.

   - In this case, `DRIVE.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')` is used.

When above flow is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
folder_id = "###"  # Please set the folder ID.

DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

results = DRIVE.files().list(pageSize=1, fields="files(modifiedTime,name,id)", orderBy="modifiedTime desc", q="'" + folder_id + "' in parents and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'", supportsAllDrives=True, includeItemsFromAllDrives=True).execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if items:
    file_id = items[0]['id']
    file_name = items[0]['name']
    request = DRIVE.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    fh = io.FileIO(file_name + '.xlsx', mode='wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

#### Note:

- From your script, I couldn't correctly understand about `DRIVE` and `team_drive.DRIVE`. In this case, from `DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))`, I used `DRIVE`. If this cannot be used, please modify it.

#### Reference:

- [Files: list in Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: @delalma Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand about your goal by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to get the URL's of files in a Drive folder:

```py
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
myDrive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

def getGDriveFileLinks(drive, folder_id, mime_type=None):
  """
  Returns a list of dicts of pairs of file names and shareable links
  drive: a GoogleDrive object with credentials https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html?highlight=googledrive#pydrive.drive.GoogleDrive
  folder_id: a folderID of the folderID containing the file (grab it from the folder's URL)
  mime_type (optional): the identifier of the filetype https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types,
                        https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
  """
  file_list = []
  mime_type_query = "mimeType='{}' and ".format(mime_type) if mime_type != None else ''
  files = drive.ListFile({'q': mime_type_query + "'{}' in parents".format(folder_id)}).GetList()
  for file in files:
    keys = file.keys()
    if 'alternateLink' in keys:
      link = file['alternateLink']
    elif 'webContentLink' in keys:
      link = file['webContentLink']
    elif 'webViewLink' in keys:
      link = file['webViewLink']
    else:
      try:
        file.InsertPermission({
                            'type': 'anyone',
                            'value': 'anyone',
                            'role': 'reader'})
        link = file['alternateLink']
      except (HttpError, ApiRequestError):
        link = 'Insufficient permissions for this file'

    if 'title' in keys:
      name = file['title']
    else:
      name = file['id']
    
    file_list.append({'name': name, 'link': link})
  
  return file_list

print(getGDriveFileLinks(myDrive, 'folder_id'))
```

Then, the URL can be used to retrieve the file using `pydrive`.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone uses ruby and needs help, this command return IO.

```
drive.export_file(sheet_id, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

ref: https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/DriveV3/DriveService.html#export_file-instance_method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).